# Why put hidden input tag above a HTML5 DOCTYPE declaration

Tags: php, html, legacy-code

I am currently working on some legacy HTML/PHP code. A number of the website's pages contain the following code:

```
<input name="ip address" id="ip" type="hidden" value="">

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>
```

others contain this code...

```
<input name="ip address" id="ip" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR]; ?>">

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>
```

still others contain this code ...

```
<?php $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR]; ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>
```

This is of course not valid HTML, but why would someone do this. Is it an old hack of some kind ?? - or perhaps just scrambled code.

Comment: Neither of the last two are even valid as they don't have a closing quote at the end. The first two seem to be attempts to log the visitors IP, although I don't see any rhyme or reason. $_SERVER does not need to be rendered before the first byte like some other PHP code does, but it seems whoever placed it there was most interested in visitor IPs, for whatever reason. What's more, the second line would print the remote IP before the rest of the markup. The third line essentially does nothing as there is no assignment. Seems mysterious and wholly unuseful if you ask me.

Comment: Looks to me, as if the author of those lines did not have valid HTML in mind. I am not aware of any "hack". Have you searched the code, if the name or id is being used?

Comment: I can't find any JavaScript that refers to the input tag at all. And of course, even if browser accepts it, it is not within a <form> tag so the browser won't submit it the regular way. Future down there is what appears to be code that handles form submissions, one line contains ...  $IP = $_POST['ip']; - but if the IP address it's not submitted then I don't see the purpose. I also don't know why they didn't just go $IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

Comment: "The third line essentially does nothing as there is no assignment. Seems mysterious and wholly unuseful if you ask me" - the joys of legacy code